# Interpret roman numeral and returns a numerical value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ('please enter a roman numeral')
romannum = input()
lenrm = len(romannum)
total = 0
for i in range (lenrm):
    numone = 0
    numtwo = 0

    if (romannum[i]).lower() == 'i':
        numone = numone + 1

    if (romannum[i]).lower() == 'v':
        numone = numone + 5

    if (romannum[i]).lower() == 'x':
        numone = numone + 10

    if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'i':
        numtwo = numtwo + 1

    if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'v':
        numtwo = numtwo + 5

    if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'x':
        numtwo = numtwo + 10


    if numone < numtwo:
        total = total + (numtwo - numone)
    else:
        total = total + numone
        i += 1
print (total)
```

With an input of `xiv`, I am getting an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\poona\Python\roman_numeral_reader.py", line 18, in <module>
    if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'i':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have en input of length 5 lets say IIIII now you take the range(5) this means the highest value it will iterate over is 4 (from 0 to 4 including both) now index 4 is the last index in your 5 index long number since we start counting indexes from 0 so when you plus it by 1 you get index 5 which is out of range.

in your case

```
romannum = "xiv"
lenrm = 3
total = 0
for i in [0,1,2]: # for i in range(3):
    ...
    if (romannum[3]).lower() == 'i': # if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'i':
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks briefly like you're trying to access the character next to `v` in `xiv`, which of course, is out of bound.

I suggest checking for boundary before trying to determine the next character:

```
for i in range (lenrm):
    numone = 0
    numtwo = 0

    if (romannum[i]).lower() == 'i':
        numone = numone + 1

    if (romannum[i]).lower() == 'v':
        numone = numone + 5

    if (romannum[i]).lower() == 'x':
        numone = numone + 10

    if i + 1 < lenrm:  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'i':
            numtwo = numtwo + 1

        if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'v':
            numtwo = numtwo + 5

        if (romannum[i + 1]).lower() == 'x':
            numtwo = numtwo + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rom2dec(char):
    for s in (('I', 1), ('V', 5), ('X', 10), ('L', 50),
              ('C', 100), ('D', 500), ('M', 1000)):
        if char == s[0]: return s[1]

total=0
prev=0
romannum = input('Roman Numeral: ').upper()

for s in reversed(romannum):
    i = rom2dec(s)

    if i < prev:
        total -= i
    else:
        total += i

    prev = i

print(total)
```

Your issue is that the error `string index out of range`
means that you are attempting to access a character index
not within the bounds of the strings length.
A string is 0 based thus the 1st character is at index 0.

With your use of `romannum[i + 1]`, you need ensure that
`i + 1` is not larger than the length of the string stored
in the variable named `romannum` minus 1 as it is 0 based.

Roman Numerals tend to work in reverse with summing
i.e. `I` before `V` is interpreted as 4 as `I` is less than
`V` and precedes `V`.

So if the string is reversed, then change each character to it`s
decimal equivalent and then compare to the last stored decimal
value to determine if to add or subtract the current decimal number.

Comment: Isn't `rom2dec` just `lambda char: {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}.get(char, 0)`?

Comment: @AdamSmith, your lambda is similar and can return the same result. Thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Was really interested in this concept, heres a different perspective that would allow you to modify it more easily if you wanted to add more numerals like `L`, `C`, `D`, and `M`, cheers!

```
while True:
    numeral = input("Enter a Roman Numeral: ")

    numeral = list(numeral.lower())

    final = 0 

    for index, items in enumerate(numeral):

        if items == 'x':
            if index == 0:
                final += 10
            elif numeral[index - 1] != 'i':
                final += 10
            else:
                final += 9

        elif items == 'v':
            if index == 0:
                final += 5
            elif numeral[index - 1] != 'i':
                final += 5
            else:
                final += 4    

        elif items == 'i':
            if index == len(numeral)-1: 
                final += 1
            elif numeral[index + 1] != 'v' and numeral[index + 1] != 'x':
                final += 1
            else:
                pass

    print(final)
```